# Swagger with SpringBoot Version 1.2.2 is not working

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger, swagger-2.0, springfox

I am trying to integrate the swagger to my spring boot application.

Spring Version: 1.2.2.RELEASE
Java Version: 8

Swagger Maven Dependency

```
<swagger.version>2.0.1</swagger.version>
<swagger-annotations.version>1.5.21</swagger-annotations.version>
<swagger-models.version>1.5.21</swagger-models.version>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
    <version>${swagger.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
    <version>${swagger.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
    <artifactId>swagger-annotations</artifactId>
    <version>${swagger-annotations.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
    <artifactId>swagger-models</artifactId>
    <version>${swagger-models.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

The configuration file is

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Swagger2UiConfiguration {


    public Docket postsApi() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2).groupName("public-api").select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.withClassAnnotation(RestController.class)).paths(PathSelectors.any())
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Docket apiDoc(ServletContext servletContext) {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .host("http://localhost:8080")
                .pathProvider(new RelativePathProvider(servletContext) {
                    @Override
                    public String getApplicationBasePath() {
                        return "/services";
                    }
                });
    }

    private Predicate<String> postPaths() {
        return or(regex("/myproject/services/*"));
    }

    private ApiInfo apiInfo() {
        return new ApiInfoBuilder().title("EMP").description("EMP Swagger Test").version("1.0").build();
    }

}
```

When running the application I can see the following logs,

```
2020-07-03 20:50:29,218 [ INFO] [] [localhost-startStop-1] (AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:220) - Mapped "{[/v2/api-docs],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[application/json || application/hal+json],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<springfox.documentation.spring.web.json.Json> springfox.documentation.swagger2.web.Swagger2Controller.getDocumentation(java.lang.String,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
2020-07-03 20:50:29,225 [ INFO] [] [localhost-startStop-1] (AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:220) - Mapped "{[/swagger-resources/configuration/security],methods=[],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<springfox.documentation.swagger.web.SecurityConfiguration> springfox.documentation.swagger.web.ApiResourceController.securityConfiguration()
2020-07-03 20:50:29,227 [ INFO] [] [localhost-startStop-1] (AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:220) - Mapped "{[/swagger-resources/configuration/ui],methods=[],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<springfox.documentation.swagger.web.UiConfiguration> springfox.documentation.swagger.web.ApiResourceController.uiConfiguration()
2020-07-03 20:50:29,228 [ INFO] [] [localhost-startStop-1] (AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:220) - Mapped "{[/swagger-resources],methods=[],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.List<springfox.documentation.swagger.web.SwaggerResource>> springfox.documentation.swagger.web.ApiResourceController.swaggerResources()
```

Still, the Swagger-UI URL returns 404.

```
http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui.html
http://localhost:8080/myproject/services/swagger-ui.html
```

Am I missing anything? Any help is very much useful.

P.S: After googling so many pages, I suspect it can be version compatibility. If so, I can not upgrade my spring-boot version. In that case, how can I integrate Swagger? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added the following additional configurations,

1. Maven Dependency,

> ```
> <dependency>
>     <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
>     <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
>     <version>2.6.1</version>
> </dependency>
> <dependency>
>   <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
>   <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
>   <version>2.6.1</version>
> </dependency>
> ```

2. Swagger config class, allowed all the URLs

   ```
   @Bean
   public Docket api() {
       return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
               .select()
               .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
               .paths(PathSelectors.any())
               .build();
   }
   ```
3. Accessed the following URL,

> `http://localhost:8080/<projectName>/swagger-ui.html#/`

Comment: did you get it working? could you upload to github as example? i'm facing the same, is an headache :/ thanks!

Comment: @C.B. I dont have that code with me now. With the above configuration it started working.

Answer (score 0):

I think something messed with your dependency. You need only two dependencies.
I am using only these two dependencies.

1. springfox-swagger2
2. springfox-swagger-ui

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
    <version>${swagger.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
    <version>${swagger.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Ok, I could integrate it successfully now, with few additional configurations. I will update the answer. Thank you for your response.

Comment: Good to know that